# How to configure log4net for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, log4net

I am trying to use Log4Net for 
Xamarin forms Project (Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS)

to write a temp log file

- How can I configure it?
  where should I add appender code?

[image]

- Is there permission required and what is the preferred path should I use for the log file for Android and iOS?